# What is the source of this TranspilerError when running qasm file?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qasm

[image]

I want to run this qasm file using IBM device.
However, there's always an error:

```
qiskit.transpiler.exceptions.TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (16) in circuit0 is greater than maximum (5) in the coupling_map'
```

How does this error come?

How can I set up the initial mapping when running this qasm file?
How to run the qasm file in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you are transpiling for a backend with 5 qubits, but this circuit is defined over a 16 qubit register (line 3 `qreg q[16];`).

To avoid this error you can either update your qasm to work over a register of 5 qubits, or transpile for a different backend. I think that the simulator is the only available device that will run up to 16 qubits.